# Read varying number of variables from file

Tags: c++, vector, file-read

I have got a file that looks like:

```
1.23 2.34 4.4 6.5 3.4
3.43 5.34 5.44 4.5 1.4
.... and so on
```

So there is many lines that are divided by space. Actually I am reading them with:

```
double values[5];
while (infile >> values[0] >> values[1] >> values[2] >> values[3] >> values4]) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        coordinates.at(x).values.push_back(values[j]);
    }
 x++;
 }
```

And I would like to be able to change number of values in file for example from 5 to 20. Is there any quick way of doing this? All I found was reading whole line as a string, then making a stream and using a lot of functions to get this values.
I know that my solution is also wrong because firstly I store them in table to put them later to a vector.

UPDATE:

Answer for this question was wrong but I sorted out it by myself:

```
string line;
while (getline(file, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);

    double val;
    while (ss >> val) {
        //do something
    }
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("data");

    while (file) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);

        std::stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss) {
            double val;
            if (ss >> val) {
                //
                // do whatever you want here
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it doesnt work: an error ***"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'"*** and there are 2 warnings: 
***" Local variable not updated in loop: file, ss "***

Comment: I have added an if check. I though that you get the point. And I dont get the error messages you get :(